# Smooth zoom jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some divs with image as background and this background is zooming on hover effect. But this zoom effect is not smooth. Is there any possibility to add something to script to make this zoom effect smooth?
Here is my html:

```
<div class="eventc" style="height: 476px;">
 <a title="#" href="#" class="under">
   <div style="background: transparent url(...) no-repeat scroll center center / cover ;" class="over-img">
     <div class="over">
      <div class="over-text">
       <div class="event-title">#</div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

And my script looks like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.over').hover(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background-size', '150%');
    }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background size
    $(this).parent().css('background-size', 'cover');
    });
});
```

So when `.over` is hover I want `.over-img` to zoom smoothly. Any idea, how can I do this?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/kpvqL4bh/

EDIT2: smooth effect like this: http://ringana.biz/de/ (hover on some img to check)

Comment: Can you make an example using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Sure, jsfidddle added

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 for sexyness, for exemple

```
 transition: background-size 0.5s ease;
```

Will give an 'animation' whenever the background size change.

EDIT : Forgot to say you obviously have to use this property in the element that hhold the background-size property itself.

See more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: I would like to use CSS3, but I think it is not possible. I'm zooming  background of div which is parent of hovered div.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work unfortunetally. You can see at fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kpvqL4bh/4/ I added this property to div (not css). Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: I edited your Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kpvqL4bh/7/

The point is that the html element that "evolve" is .over not .over-img even if it's .over-img that triggers events. Basically you were writitng "if .over-img change background-size, animate it" and then "if .over-img is :hover, change xxx property of .img" So obviously those two statements never meet each others if you think about it.

Comment: OK quick addition, just noticed that i was missing half of the fiddle because the picture were blocked by my proxy. Edited the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kpvqL4bh/8/

You can notice I edited the background size property to be 100% instead of cover because you can't animate a value if it's not numeric